# When are AWT (extended) modifiers guaranteed to be valid?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent

I'm recording AWT events (`mouse_pressed`, `mouse_released`, `key_pressed`, `key_released`, etc.) to a log to replay them back using Robot in unit tests. But I found that I sometimes need to insert `mouse_released` events when they are missing, because some of my components remove themselves on `mouse_pressed` so the `mouse_released` is never dispatched. I thought that a good approach would be to insert `mouse_released` whenever a mouse event is seen that has `modifiersEx`=`Button1` followed by an event that has `modifiersEx`=0, unless the second event is already mouse_released. But I found a problem when using a `JComboBox`.

Here's a simple main function containing a `JComboBox` with a component under it that also receives mouse events.

[image: Screenshot of window with JComboBox]

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class DemoEvents {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Test events");
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = jframe.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JComboBox jcomboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"one", "two", "three"});
        JButton jbutton = new JButton("Hello");
        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        innerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(innerPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        innerPanel.add(jcomboBox);
        innerPanel.add(jbutton);
        outerPanel.add(innerPanel);
        contentPane.add(outerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jframe.setSize(200, 200);
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        long mask =
            AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK |
            AWTEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL_EVENT_MASK |
            AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK;

        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("awt-events");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                InputEvent ev = (InputEvent)event;
                logger.info(ev.toString());
            }
        }, mask);
    }
}
```

When clicking on the `JComboBox` and clicking item "one", I get these events. The `mouse_entered` with extModifiers=Button1 doesn't make sense, because it was dispatched **after** the `mouse_released event`! Here's a simplified log from when I clicked the combo box, then clicked the first item. Look at the bolded event at the bottom:

1. MouseEvent[MOUSE_PRESSED,(1,13),button=1,modifiers=Button1,extModifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on MetalComboBoxButton[...]
2. MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(1,13),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on MetalComboBoxButton[...]
3. MouseEvent[MOUSE_MOVED,(0,14),button=0,clickCount=0] on MetalComboBoxButton[...]
4. MouseEvent[MOUSE_EXITED,(-2,15),button=0,clickCount=0] on MetalComboBoxButton[...]
5. MouseEvent[MOUSE_ENTERED,(81,15),button=0,clickCount=0] on JComboBox[...]
6. MouseEvent[MOUSE_MOVED,(81,15),button=0,clickCount=0] on JComboBox[...]
7. (more moves)
8. MouseEvent[MOUSE_EXITED,(69,24),button=0,clickCount=0] on JComboBox[...]
9. MouseEvent[MOUSE_ENTERED,(69,0),button=0,clickCount=0] on ComboPopup.popup
10. MouseEvent[MOUSE_MOVED,(69,0),button=0,clickCount=0] on ComboPopup.popup
11. MouseEvent[MOUSE_EXITED,(68,2),button=0,clickCount=0] on ComboPopup.popup
12. MouseEvent[MOUSE_ENTERED,(67,1),button=0,clickCount=0] on ComboBox.list
13. MouseEvent[MOUSE_MOVED,(67,1),button=0,clickCount=0] on ComboBox.list
14. (more moves)
15. MouseEvent[MOUSE_PRESSED,(57,9),button=1,modifiers=Button1,extModifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on ComboBox.list
16. MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(57,9),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on ComboBox.list
17. MouseEvent[MOUSE_ENTERED,(25,10),button=1,modifiers=Button1,**extModifiers=Button1**,clickCount=1] on JButton[...]
18. MouseEvent[MOUSE_MOVED,(26,10),button=0,clickCount=0] on JButton[...]

Question: When is the order of `mouse_pressed`/`mouse_released` inconsistent with the modifiers of other mouse events? Is it only `mouse_entered`/`mouse_exited` events that happen with inconsistent modifiers? Does this only happen when clicking on`JComboBox`'s popup?

I'm running Java 1.6 on Ubuntu.

Edit: included a longer log for clarity.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

On my platform, "clicking on the `JComboBox` and clicking item *one*" produces the events shown below.

The result may depend on `com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxButton`, the platform's `ComboBoxUI` delegate.  I am unable to account for the absence of `MOUSE_CLICKED` in your result. I did not move the mouse after clicking on the `JComboBox`; it appears that you did, and that result is recorded.

Note that "[Extended modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getModifiersEx%28%29) represent the state of all modal keys, such as `ALT`, `CTRL`, `META`, and the mouse buttons just *after* the event occurred," so the presence of `extModifiers` on some events does not seem inconsistent. I don't see anything indicating that [`MOUSE_MOVED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) events include any modifiers at all.

I don't know a solution to the underlying problem, except to re-examine the need for a synthetic `MOUSE_RELEASED` event. As an alternative, you might verify that a component is removed by examining the [containment hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10542850/230513).

```
May 11, 2012 10:36:36 AM DemoEvents$1 eventDispatched
INFO: java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_PRESSED,(85,9),absolute(124,58),button=1,modifiers=Button1,extModifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxButton[…]
May 11, 2012 10:36:36 AM DemoEvents$1 eventDispatched
INFO: java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(85,9),absolute(124,58),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxButton[…]
May 11, 2012 10:36:36 AM DemoEvents$1 eventDispatched
INFO: java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_CLICKED,(85,9),absolute(124,58),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxButton[…]
May 11, 2012 10:36:38 AM DemoEvents$1 eventDispatched
INFO: java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_ENTERED,(91,6),absolute(124,58),button=1,modifiers=Button1,extModifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on ComboBox.list
May 11, 2012 10:36:38 AM DemoEvents$1 eventDispatched
INFO: java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_PRESSED,(91,6),absolute(124,58),button=1,modifiers=Button1,extModifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on ComboBox.list
May 11, 2012 10:36:38 AM DemoEvents$1 eventDispatched
INFO: java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(91,6),absolute(124,58),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on ComboBox.list
```

Comment: The event that I was referring to was right after your log, after the second click. In Ubuntu, after the second mouse_released there is a mouse_entered that still has a modifier.

Comment: OK, every `MOUSE_PRESSED` has `extModifiers`, but I see it on `MOUSE_ENTERED` only during `MOUSE_DRAGGED`, i.e. while the mouse button is still down.

Comment: I don't know what's happends on *nix platform(s) +1