# inspect element in java swing application

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, element, inspect

In web applications that run with Tomcat from Eclipse, for example, we can right-click on an element in the page and inspect it (with Firebug, for example), and we can see the element's ID, class, etc. If we have a JAVA Swing application that we run from Eclipse (right-click project ==> debug as ==> eclipse application), can we do the same thing so that we can see which method, for example handles that element, or whatever? Can we inspect a JAVA Swing element as it runs (from Eclipse)? I already checked swing-inspector, but I do not want it.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there's an exact equivalent to tools like Firebug for Swing. Don't forget the fact that the DOM and some tree-like structure of panels and other elements in your Swing application are quite different by nature.

Comment: If you want to inspect instances of Swing controls at runtime, keep a reference to them in your code and then do so with Eclipse's debugger. If your question is whether there is a pre-existing structure in a Java Swing application that is equivalent to the html DOM, the answer is no.

Comment: There's some good stuff [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6671021/261156).

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that I can not offer you a solution for Eclipse. If you can use Netbeans it includes a [Visual Debugger feature](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual.html). It is simple to use and it is integrated in Netbeans by default.