# cannot see JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am wondering why I am not able to see the `topPanel` in my `controlPanel`

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class GUI {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JPanel topPanel;
private JPanel controlPanel;
private JLabel topLabel;

void createScreen() {

    frame = new JFrame("Hello");
    frame.setSize(600,600);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1)); 
    controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    controlPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    topLabel = new JLabel("WELCOME TO MY TRAINING", JLabel.CENTER);

    frame.add(topLabel);
    frame.add(controlPanel);

    topPanel = new JPanel();

    BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();

    borderLayout.setHgap(10);
    borderLayout.setVgap(10);

    topPanel.setLayout(borderLayout);
    topPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    topPanel.setSize(75,300);
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setSize(25, 25);

    topPanel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    controlPanel.add(topPanel);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     GUI gui = new GUI();
     gui.createScreen();
}

}
```

Comment: My mistake, I thought topLabel was a panel as well. Comment deleted.

Comment: `frame.pack()`?

Comment: It's always a good information if you analyse the Swing Layout information from debug output. Therefore, press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[F1] in your java console, and you get the layout output. For this and other debugging hints, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671021/how-to-debug-java-swing-layouts

Another approach for debugging to set some fancy colors to your panels. The color allows you to see which panel is shown and which one is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlowLayout uses components preferred size and not the actual size set to it.
To fix your issue set preferred size to `topPanel` instead of its `size`.

`topPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(75,300) );`

But my advice is to avoid setting size like this but instead let the `TextArea` determine the size by specifying its number of rows and columns like this:

```
topPanel.setLayout(borderLayout);
topPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
textArea = new JTextArea(10, 15);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still confused a bit, it seems to me that the text area is always the entire size of the topPanel. Is that because I am using flowlayout?

Comment: Yes. If you set `BorderLayout` to `controlPanel` it will take the whole `controlPanel`.

Comment: @isaace: you will want to read the layout manager tutorials which you can find here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).